# How to make redirect to some specific language from next.config.js by using cookies

Tags: next.js

Below you can see my `next.config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/en',
        permanent: false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see from `/` I want to direct user to specific language . When user first time came on site , it is ok to redirect on `/en/`language , but when he will change language on the site I should remember it and second time redirect user to language he choosed , I first what came to my mind save it too cookies , and then get it from there , but I haven't found any solution for next js config I can use. Is it possible to make it from `next.config.js` or maybe there some another way to make it better ?

Answer (score 2):

Next.js has automatic locale detection when you land on the *root* of the site. So the user will be redirected to his locale if the application supports it, or it will be served the default locale.

Next.js also honors the `NEXT_LOCALE` cookie, so if that cookie is present in the user's browser, it will be used to redirect the user to the locale of the cookie for example, `NEXT_LOCALE=fr` will always redirect the user to the `fr` locale regardless of the user's true browser locale.

If your application has a way for the user to choose his locale when it does, just set the cookie with the chosen locale, and you are good to go.